# Translation for German word "doch"

Tags: translation

So there's this beautiful German word "doch" which is mostly used to contradict a contradiction.

Example:

> Ich war heute schon draußen
>   *I already went outside today*
>
> Nein warst du nicht
>   *No you weren't*
>
> **Doch**

I know there's no one-word translation for it, but **how can I express it in English in this context?**

Comment: No one-word translation? Google offers "but" and other 12 translations for "doch". Maybe if you describe some context or include an example of what you are looking for. "contradict a contradiction" is not very helpful.

Comment: French has an equivalent word- Si, but you are right that there is no single-word equivalent in English for doch as a positive answer to a negative statement. See the Cambridge Dictionary: they propose  "Yes, I do/will/have" as the translation. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/doch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have, **yes but**, expressed in the midwestern U.S. as, **yahbut** (rhymes with rabbit and is spoken as a single word).
>
> It is always expressed in the positive, **yes but**, and never, **no
>   but**.
>
> The **yes** acknowledges the original contradiction, the
>   **but** sets the stage for the subsequent contra-contradiction, and the phrase following **but** contradicts.

Example --

p1: "I went to the store."

p2: "You lounged on the couch all day!"

p1: "Yes but I got up and went to the store at around 10 p.m."

Comment: Note:  Both **yes but** and **no but** can be used to answer a question and then provide additional information but only **yes but** can stand alone as a contra-contradiction.

Comment: What you suggested isn't a contradiction to the first contradiction, it's rather a confirmation/expansion of the contradiction

Comment: @Nanogamer7  Is it the time of day thing that is confusing?  Should I change it to a _daylight_ hour like 4 p.m.?  If you suggest I've lounged on the couch all day and reply that I went to the store, then obviously I have not lounged on the couch all day.  That would, I believe, be a contradiction.

Comment: @Nanogamer7  I see your edits.  My answer does not address _doch_ as you use it.  There is no equivalent.

Comment: 'Yes' sounds like a confirmation to me, so I assumed it's no contradiction. If it actually is a contradiction, can you please explain it further?

Comment: @Nanogamer7 I thought I had addressed it in my answer.  **Yes** merely acknowledges the original contradiction.  It is like saying, "I have heard and I understand your contradiction _but you have overlooked something_."  **Yes** does not mean that you _agree_ with the contradiction but that you understand it and you understand why it is wrong.  The **but** introduces your counter contradiction; the explanation for why the contradiction is incorrect.

Comment: Ok... Is *'Yes but'* usable alone or do you need something behind it?

Comment: @Nanogamer7 Excellent question.  "Yes but," can stand alone and would come quite close in meaning to 'doch'.  People do say, "Yes but."  It means something like, "I understand and acknowledge your contradiction _but your contradiction is incorrect_."

Answer (score 2):

No you were not. - Was, too!

No you did not. - Did, too!

No you can not. - Can, too!
Etc...

No you did not. - I so did!

These are all mostly used in childrens' talk, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can I make a suggestion as a German?

I have already been outside today. No, you haven't. Yes, I have!

Comment: It's a possible translation but far not as *[Schlagkräftig, dunno the English word for it]* as 'doch'